# Logic help. Storing old and new incoming data

Tags: c#, string

I need to come up with an algorithm, and I think it's rather simple but for the life of me I cannot figure it out.

I have two strings:

```
string oldData;
string newData;
```

These variables initially will start out empty.I need a way to store previous data, and new incoming data. Sometimes the incoming data will be the same, so there will be no change necessary. If the new incoming data is different, then oldData will get the previous newData, and newData will get the new incoming data.

Comment: Unless they're huge strings and you're processing oodles of data, why not just copy the new data every time?

Answer (score 1):

The above would work, but if you wanted to make them like properties of a class, you could do something like

```
public YourClass
{

   string oldValue;
   string newValue;
   public string NewValue
   { get { return newValue; }
     set { if( ! value.Equals( newValue ))
           {
              oldValue = newValue; 
              newValue = value; 
           }
         }
   }

}
```

Then, you could do binding to the property both within WinForms or WPF application too.

Answer (score 0):

I would think it would be something like:

```
void checkData(string newData) {
    if ( newData != oldData ) {
        oldData = newData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of you question since it seems pretty obvious but would something like this work ? :

```
string oldData;
string newData;

void newStringIncoming(string myNewString)
{
   if(myNewString != newData)
   {
      oldData = newData;
      newData = myNewString;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just do something like this?

```
private string YourMethodNameHere(string oldValue,string newValue)
{
  if(old != newValue)
    return newValue;
  return oldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complex answer using an event which will allow you to add extra events without sticking them in the setter

```
public string OldData { get; set; }
private string _newData;
public string NewData
{
    get { return _newData; }
    set
    {
        if (value.Equals(_newData)) { return; }

        _newData = value;
        DataChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

private event EventHandler DataChanged;

public DataHolder()
{

    DataChanged = (sender, args) =>
    {
        DataHolder dataHolder = sender as DataHolder;
        if (dataHolder != null)
        {
            dataHolder.OldData = NewData;
        }
    };
}
```